# How to display several user inputted answers and how to write it all to a text file

Tags: javascript, java, try-catch, user-input, jgrasp

So I ran into another problem with my code. What I want to do is to be able to output different entries the user has inputted. I also want to be able to have all said entries be outputted to a .txt file. I will be using this for Microsoft Excel later. This my code so far:

```
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.text.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Project1{


  public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException

{

  String fileName = "out.txt";
  try {


    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Project1.out");

    String employee_Fname;
    String employee_Lname;
    String employee_city;
    String employee_state;
    double empzip;
    String employee_job;
    double empsal;
    char again;
    int count = 1;
    String answer;

    do {

        System.out.print("Enter Employees First Name: ");
        employee_Fname = user_input.next();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter the employee's last name: ");
        employee_Lname = user_input.next();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter employee's city: ");
        employee_city = user_input.next();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter employee's state: ");
        employee_state = user_input.next();
        employee_state.toUpperCase();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter employee's zipcode: ");
        empzip = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter employee's job title: ");
        employee_job = user_input.next();
        System.out.println();

        System.out.print("Enter employee's salary: ");
        empsal = keyboard.nextDouble();
        System.out.println();



        while(empsal > 2000000) {
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("Invalid salary entered! Please tryn again.");

            System.out.print("Enter employee's salary: ");
            empsal = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println();



            System.out.println();
        }



        System.out.print("Do you want to enter another employee? Y/N?");
        answer = keyboard.next();

    } while (answer.equals("Y"));

    outFile.printf("Employee first name is: %n "+ employee_Fname +"%n");
    outFile.printf("Employee last name is: %n " + employee_Lname +"%n");
    outFile.printf("Employee city is: %n " + employee_city + "%n");
    outFile.printf("Employee state is: %n " + employee_state +"%n");
    outFile.printf("Employee zipcode is: %n " + empzip + "%n");
    outFile.printf("Employee job is: %n  " + employee_job +"%n");
    outFile.printf("Employee salary is:  %n " + empsal +"%n");

    outFile.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

  e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

The output however doesn't even give me a text file and if I entered in a second entry it deletes the entry I had before and only displays the last entered entry. Maybe I put the "try" to early?

EDIT: HEY nevermind about the text part I figured it out! Turns out I didn't define the "filename" correctly. However, I'm still having troubles with my program. I still need to help with the fact that it won't let me display anything else but the last entered entry. Not only that but the txt file is empty. I'm glad I at least got the txt file to show up but it's empty.

`

Comment: You are opening the file for writing with the `PrintWriter(String)` constructor, which is documented as "If the file exists then it will be truncated to zero size." Every time you open the file, you destroy what was there. You need to use one of the constructors of `FileOutputStream` that takes the `boolean append` parameter, and then use that when creating your PrintWriter.

Comment: See I did that and it's giving me the text file but the text file is empty still and nothing changed with the fact that the last inputted entry is the only one displayed:     PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter("Project1.out");
        PrintWriter outputStream = new PrintWriter(fileName);

Comment: The other problem is that you're writing to the file outside of the while-loop so the results from the previous entry is being lost.

Comment: @Jason got it right. I didn't read the code closely enough. You would really benefit from creating a few helper methods to read in strings and numbers, with prompts. You shouldn't be creating multiple Scanners, either. Just create one. And using `next()` is a bad practice. In particular, if a city name has two words, like "New York", your code will break. Use `nextLine()` instead. For numbers, too.

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the results to the file before you move onto the next employee. Also, you need to use a PrintWriter that takes a FileWriter, and ultimately a File so that you can append instead of overwritting the contents as another user noted.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fileName = "out.txt";

        try {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

            Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

            String employee_Fname;

            String employee_Lname;

            String employee_city;

            String employee_state;

            double empzip;

            String employee_job;

            double empsal;

            char again;

            int count = 1;

            String answer;

            do {
                System.out.print("Enter Employees First Name: ");
                employee_Fname = user_input.next();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter the employee's last name: ");
                employee_Lname = user_input.next();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter employee's city: ");
                employee_city = user_input.next();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter employee's state: ");
                employee_state = user_input.next();
                employee_state.toUpperCase();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter employee's zipcode: ");
                empzip = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter employee's job title: ");
                employee_job = user_input.next();
                System.out.println();

                System.out.print("Enter employee's salary: ");
                empsal = keyboard.nextDouble();
                System.out.println();

                while (empsal > 2000000) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Invalid salary entered! Please tryn again.");

                    System.out.print("Enter employee's salary: ");
                    empsal = keyboard.nextDouble();
                    System.out.println();


                    System.out.println();
                }

                try (PrintWriter outFile = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(new File("Project1.out"), true))) {
                    outFile.printf("Employee first name is: %n " + employee_Fname + "%n");
                    outFile.printf("Employee last name is: %n " + employee_Lname + "%n");
                    outFile.printf("Employee city is: %n " + employee_city + "%n");
                    outFile.printf("Employee state is: %n " + employee_state + "%n");
                    outFile.printf("Employee zipcode is: %n " + empzip + "%n");
                    outFile.printf("Employee job is: %n  " + employee_job + "%n");
                    outFile.printf("Employee salary is:  %n " + empsal + "%n");
                }

                System.out.print("Do you want to enter another employee? Y/N?");

                answer = keyboard.next();
            } while (answer.equals("Y"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't you need to close the outfile? Like: outFile.close();
          outputStream.close();

Comment: @CarryDove You should be using a try-with-resources statement so that the file is closed automatically upon exiting the try block.

Comment: That is a fantastic question. You actually dont! This is because the Closeable object is wrapped in something called a try-with-resources! Great question.

Comment: So what would happen if I include them anyway? Oh and the txt file is still empty. Is it because I included the outFile.close? I heard about buffedwriter should I use that?

Comment: If you call close it doesn't make a difference. It's just a nice way of ensuring that it's closed once the Closeable falls out of scope. Also, the contents are being written to Project1.out file, make sure ur trying to find that file! I just tested and it worked fine (loosly).